# 'docker ps' command throws Forbidden error

Tags: docker

I am running docker tool on Windows-7. When I run the command `docker ps` from Docker Quickstart Terminal, it throws below error:

> An error occurred trying to connect: Get
>   https://192.168.99.100:2376/v1.24/containers/json: Forbidden

Please let me know how to fix this error. Thanks.

Comment: It would be real helpful to know why this question got downvoted so that I don't make the same mistake/s again, thanks.

Comment: I down voted and voted to close as it is totally unclear what you are asking. See the http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask page for help clarifying your question.

Comment: Is your docker daemon running?

Comment: If you have a local vanilla docker installation, then something is really wrong. Reinstall? If you messed with the parameters, you might want to check the ENV variables and or a .docker config file (don't know where that is on Windows...)...

Comment: @AyonNahiyan: I am not sure how to check if docker daemon is running. Should I be looking into the host os (Windows7), where docker tool is installed or the docker machine?

Comment: @Sajal: its just the process that has keep running, to allow you to run other docker ccommands. Its usually the step2 here: https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/

Answer (score 1):

Earlier, following [Common-Proxy-Issues-&-Fixes](https://github.com/docker/kitematic/wiki/Common-Proxy-Issues-&-Fixes), I have added `HTTP_PROXY` and `HTTPS_PROXY` in my Windows environments. Probably after this only, I started to face above mentioned issue. The problem got resolved after removing these.